# .NET Core Web API not reading environment correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 2.0 Web API that is failing to read the environment specific app.settings file. As far as I can tell I have followed all the relevant steps.

This is my `Startup.cs` constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

I then have an `appsettings.json` file structure of:

```
appsettings.json
  -appsettings.debug.json
  -appsettings.release.json
  -appsettings.production.json
```

And on the server where my API is deployed to I have a system environment variable key/value pair of

`Variable = ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Value = Release`

But when I make calls into the API the `appsettings.production.json` values are used, which (from what I understand) is the default when an environment variable of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is not found.

Thoughts on what my setup might be missing to cause this default behavior?

Comment: Maybe a case related issue ? Something like that 
`string settingsFilePath = $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json";`

Comment: @ChristopherJ. the docs say that it is case insensitive, and my tests have shown the same.

Comment: @bcwiniger the `AddJsonFile` method is definitely case-sensitive when checking the file name, so rename your file to `appsettings.Release.json` or use `.ToLower()` approach

Comment: @Set according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) it is case insensitive. "On Windows and macOS, the specified environment name is case insensitive. Whether you set the variable to Development or development or DEVELOPMENT the results will be the same". I have tried changing the env variable to match the appsettings file name, and have tried the `.ToLower()` method as well w/o luck. I am printing out the name of the environment stored in `IHostingEnvironment` and it is coming back `Production`.

Comment: AddJsonFile just works with file name, provided as a first string parameter. You construct this string using env.EnvironmentName - so this string value depends on case of your env name. 2 Fact that you always have only 'Production' as value from IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName means that you didn't properly define env name.

Comment: @Set I used the solution marked as accepted below and things work fine now even though I changed the casing back to be different and verified that it is reading a different cased environment variable. So it looks like it is case insensitive (though the docs do mention that a Linux deployed app would be case sensitive).

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, the configuration isn’t loaded within the `Startup` constructor anymore. It’s being built by the `WebHost`. So something is off in your setup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You haven't specified, but I'm assuming your running in IIS. If that's the case, you need to edit the advanced properties of your App Pool and set the "Load User Profile" option to true. Otherwise, it won't actually read from your environment variables.

Comment: 'Load User Profile', but this saved me.  Thanks.